# Read XML Get Request Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Trying to use an API which sends data via GET in XML format

Here is my code

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getpredictions?key=JcCyb84hceaH4zhFyrxgEvfKj&stpid=1876l',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function( data ) {
          alert("Success : "+data);
      }
    });
```

Im getting this error

www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getpredictions?key=JcCyb84hceaH4zhFyrx…1876l&callback=jQuery111101477464847266674_1440527282431&_=1440527282432:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Um, change dataType to xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/getpredictions?key=JcCyb84hceaH4zhFyrxgEvfKj&stpid=1876l',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function( data ) {
      alert("Success : "+data);
  }
});
```

Datatype should be xml, if you know what kind of information you will get, try to always provide information to the request.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is jsonp maybe you need to include a library from your API somewhere on your site so it can call the approperiate javascript function on callback to process the data. Also it is possible that you need a different dataType value such as XML.

Be careful about posting your key online since now other people can use your account. I would recommend editing that out and changing the key since it's already compromised. Unless it's a test key and you are ok with sharing it :)